# Make a layer over an image and adjust its co-ordinates by touch

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, objective-c, touch

I need to make a layer over an image and adjust the layer to fit to image and get its co-ordinates of the layer.

I need to adjust the layer by touch and pinch.

The sample image is as below. I need to do this in ios, and can I get any ideas to do this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of programming in objective c? Have you heard of cocoa2D? If not then I suggest you use cocos2D for this project as it is a good user friendly engine which has a heap of tutorials. I don't think it would be that difficult to accomplish what you have just stated :)

Comment: @Savlon Yes I know about cocoa2D I posted here not to know the name of the framework. Need some points to do this, like a starter. And if it is that easy can you post as an answer, how to do??

Comment: Yes I know this. However, this isn't a "write my code" for me site... I think you should search for some tutorials on google before posting your question here. All you want to do is adjust an image/layer via touch yes? That is simple... The pinch zooming is a little harder... Search google for pinch zooming tutorial objective c... I'm sure there are a lot of them. EDIT: here is a pinch zoom tutorial http://www.techpaa.com/2011/03/pinch-zoom-using-uipinchgesturerecogniz.html?m=1 enjoy

Comment: I'm still not sure what the question is: What do you mean by "layer over an image"? Do you want to do edge detection of an image and generate vertices of some sort? Do you want to parameterize the image so that if you push or pull on a vertex it will move that corresponding part of the image?

Comment: The human image is in background and the blue web is in the fore ground. I need the fore ground image blue web to move to fit the face of the human.